# showing javascript dynamic content and text side by side

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I want to show a JavaScript based dynamic content and some text beside each other in HTML.
To show them side by side, I am using a border-less table .

The problem is that I am able to see the result correctly when the HTML code is ran in [Html Code Tester](http://www.draac.com/htmltester.html) but when seen live on my domain , the adjacent columns are not on the same level. The columns are placed one above other . I have used the **valign** attribute to make sure the dynamic content fits in the row height but that doesn't help too.

The Webpage (with incorrect preview) is [this](http://avi-aryan.github.io/templates/footer.html) and its source code in the git repository is [this](https://github.com/avi-aryan/avi-aryan.github.com/blob/master/templates/footer.html).
The code used for testing with [HTML Code Tester](http://www.draac.com/htmltester.html) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/avi-aryan/6184295)

Comment: Add the following CSS property to your page in the `head` tag: `<style type="text/css">td{ display:inline-block; }</style>`

Comment: @JeffNoel It works but now I have lost aligning of the G+ dynamic gadget. You can see [this](http://avi-aryan.github.io/templates/footer.html) for the changes.

Comment: Google devs are brilliant at minifying their code. You could probably check the classes of the created elements and try to align them by adding an offset `margin-left` (either positive or negative)